# VS Code Scroll Map (Minimap)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am searching for something like [this](https://github.com/atom-minimap/minimap) extension for VS Code. Any suggestion?

Comment: ... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42561099/vs-code-minimap-location-highlighting for some new additional options for coloring the minimap sidebar, including opacity, which might be of interest.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Finally, we have the code mini-map feature in the February 2017 release (1.10)!

To enable it, open your editor settings and add the following

```
"editor.minimap.enabled": true
```

Answer (score 23):

This is a [top request](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7752789-minimap) in User Voice. Currently not implemented in product nor as an extension.

Comment: Note that this is now the top request on GitHub - https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/4865

Answer (score 7):

Additional settings in Minimap (For love of Minimap):

1) to render blocks instead of characters for better visualization on the Minimap:

```
"editor.minimap.renderCharacters":false
```

2) highlight slider on the map:

```
"editor.minimap.showSlider": "always"
```

Answer (score 4):

Finally! Version 1.10 brings this long missing feature.
[Official announcement](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_preview-minimap)

> No need to edit any settings! It's enabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can track an open issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/4865). They recently launched a beta version of the minimap with the last insider release. Have a look, it looks great! [Link to visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)