# How to make VS Code minimap always highlight my screen location?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was really excited to see VS Code finally added a minimap option for easier navigation. However, I've been really frustrated that the translucent rectangle showing your current location in a file only shows up when you hover over the minimap. A visual example of what I mean:

Without cursor:
[image: Without cursor]
With cursor:
[image: With cursor]

When using this feature in other editors, I find a lot of value comes from quickly seeing where I am in a file. Does anyone know if there is a setting/extension/hack that will keep the rectangle visible?

Comment: As written by @daslicious from 2019 this setiing is in the "Settings". Just browse to "Settings" and search for "minimap" you'll find "Minimap:show slider". I'm wondering why this feature is not set as default "always". It is more intuitive and immediate to have it visible

Comment: Other "minimap" settings you can tweak in "settings.json" (Ctrl + comma in windows) can be found in [API-minimap](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#minimap)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

From the stable version [1.14 (June 2017)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_14#_minimap) there is an option in `settings.json`:

```
"editor.minimap.showSlider": "always"
```

Comment: This option is in the settings gui now

Answer (score 7):

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/78195302/836330 to add header text into your minimap like

[image: minimap section headers]

---

Of interest to some may be that v1.43 added three new `colorCustomizations` that affect the minimap slider color, including opacity (last two digits in the settings:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  "minimapSlider.background": "#ff000060",
  "minimapSlider.hoverBackground": "#ff0000",
  "minimapSlider.activeBackground": "#2f00ff50"
}
```

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/90631 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_43.md#minimap-background-and-slider-colors

Answer (score 3):

It appears this is already being tracked in a feature request:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21784

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a way to do it without [building VS Code from source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute#build-and-run-from-source) as it's just a small change to the [minimap.css file](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/minimap/minimap.css) of setting the **opacity: 0;** to **opacity: 1**;

```
.monaco-editor .minimap-slider {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 100ms linear;
}
```

I can't override the default css from the user settings with
**"editor.minimap-slider.opacity": 1,**

But I am a noob at this kind of hack.

Answer (score 0):

Use:
"editor.minimap.showSlider":"always",

in the user setting fiel - settings.json file